# Convert "The LINQ expression could not be translated" warning into an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I was looking at my logs recently, and I noticed that one of my queries was causing a warning that said "The LINQ expression '{expression}' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally." This is because of a mistake that I made in my query expression.

I was able to fix this issue without too much trouble. My question is: How can I detect this situation in the future without manually looking at the logs?

Two possible solutions (neither of which I know how to implement):

- Change the warning into an error
- Write a test that detects the problem. I currently have tests that use an in memory database to test other aspects of the query.

My goal is to be able to prevent a mistake like this from accidentally slipping into production.

Comment: Changing the warning into error

Comment: That's all well-documented. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Comment: @GertArnold That's exactly the link I needed. If you convert this info to answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the link provided by @GertArnold, I was able to convert the warning into an error using the following code:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("connection-string");
        options.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
    }
)
```